# Unable to run "git push heroku master"

Tags: heroku, playframework, sbt

I've tried on windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04. In both cases, I got errors about unable to get dependencies. I'm following the instructions from http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTodoList and http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaTodoList

```
      Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/net/java/dev/jna/j
na/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.jar ...

       :: problems summary ::
       :::: WARNINGS
                [FAILED     ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3!jna.jar: The HTTP respo
nse code for http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2
.3/jna-3.2.3.jar did not indicate a success. See log for more detail. (40ms)

                [FAILED     ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3!jna.jar: The HTTP respo
nse code for http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2
.3/jna-3.2.3.jar did not indicate a success. See log for more detail. (40ms)

        ==== heroku-central: tried

          http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/
jna-3.2.3.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

                :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3!jna.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


       :::: ERRORS
        SERVER ERROR: Gateway Timeout url=http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-cen
tral/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.jar


       :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
       download failed: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3!jna.jar
       Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
         (see /tmp/build_2alkkctoiqzvf/project/boot/update.log for complete log)

       Error: Could not retrieve jna 3.2.3
 !     Failed to build app with sbt
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.0 app

To git@heroku.com:falling-stone-8800.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:falling-stone-8800.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a systemwide error today (June 10, 2012). There's most likely nothing wrong with your code or deployment method, it may just be a Heroku hiccup. I have been unable to push changes to my (working) Java Play 2.0 app all morning due to the same system error.

I have filed a ticket and would urge others to do the same.

Comment: Thanks. Makes me feel assured. The same issue is also here. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/epx7HrUl6PY . It's a bad timing on heroku's part since I just picked up play! last night and have been trying a few hours to get heroku to work.

Comment: Yep.. you'll see I commented there as well :D